# AWS Lambda initialization code (Python) mystery

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a Python 3.6 Lambda function that needs to download dependencies into /tmp (I use layers as well, but /tmp is needed due to size limitations) and import them. I have the code that does the download-zip-and-extract-to-temp part before the handler with the expectation that it only needs to be downloaded on cold start. Say it looks like below (pseudocode):

```
log('Cold start')
download_deps() # has some log statements of its own
log('init end')

def handler(event, context):
...
```

Most of the time it works fine. However, every now and then the logs stop showing up somewhere during initialization. (For e.g. it says "Cold start", but not "init end"; it 'dies' somewhere in download_deps).  I have exception handling in there and log everything, but nothing shows up. When the handler runs next time it runs into ImportError.

While trying to fix this, I noticed something peculiar. The initialization code is running twice on a single invocation of the Lambda. Given the above pseudocode, the logs look like:

```
Cold start
<logs from download_deps that indicate it downloaded things into /tmp>
START <RequestId> ...

<RequestId> Cold start
<logs from download_deps that indicate it skipped download because /tmp was already populated by deps>
init end
END <RequestId>
```

The "init end" part doesn't show up the first time, so logs somehow vanish again. Since it skips download the second time (/tmp is preserved), I know it's not 2 actual cold starts happening. The second time it logs 'Cold start' it includes the RequestId, but not the first time; almost as if the first initialization wasn't caused by a request, even though timing of the request on API gateway matches the timing of the first "Cold start". What is going on here?

Comment: What's the size of the download going into the /tmp folder?

Comment: So there are 2 zips, for each one I download and extract it then remove the zip. After extracting they are a bit smaller than 250 MB total.

Comment: This is interesting, we've seen a case where the logs stopped showing up due to the tmp folder running out of memory which created some hairy issues, but it doesn't appear you're up against that limit, though you did mention you're using layers, and not 100% sure that that doesn't eat into that limit.  How much memory does the lambda have to work with?  Have you throttled that up to see if that could be causing some of this?

Comment: Do you use any asynchronous mechanism in the `download_deps()`? For examples, `multithreading`, `greenlet`, `gevent`, or `asyncio`.

Comment: @JosephKing Yeah I suspected some kind of disk space issue, but according to my understanding I am within limits. I have seen a Lambda run out of disk space before but the error was logged. The Lambda is given 1024 MB of memory currently.

Comment: @PhilipTzou The download_deps() downloads the zip file from S3 and runs zipfile.extractAll on it. Doesn't use any of the things you listed.

Comment: @ITnotIT could you boost that to the max, just to rule out any sort of resource limitations?  That's definitely a pretty large project for a lambda, sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the two 'Cold start's were always ~10 seconds apart. It looks like if the initialization code takes more than ~10 seconds, it is restarted. Also, based on the duration reported in the logs, the time taken by the second initialization is included in the billed duration.

To solve my problem I moved download_deps() inside the handler, making sure that it only does anything if it needs to.

Comment: It could be that the second cold-start is coming from a concurrent Lambda instance. Once AWS Lambda notices that the requests are too many to handle by the existing pool of allocated instances, it adds instances to the pool (up to a maximum of 1000, IIRC).